# Find $y(5)$ if $(x,y)$ solves Lotka-Volterra system $(x',y')=(x-xy,xy-y)$ with $(x(0),y(0))=(600,800)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, biology

I don't remember well, but I was doing a biology problem using some Lotka-Volterra equation.

I had $\displaystyle\frac{dx}{dt}=x-xy$ and $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dt}=xy-y$.

$y(0)=800$, $x(0)=600$, compute $y(5)$

But how do I solve? Do I just take the derivative of $\displaystyle\frac{dx}{dt}$ to get $\displaystyle\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=2-3y-3x(4xy-y)$?

To get $\displaystyle \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=2-3y+3xy-12x^2y$?

But I don't even know where and or how to solve...

I know Laplace Transform and separation methods.

Comment: you may try the picard's method for simultaneous differential equations.

Comment: The symbolic solutions are very messy. Are you are looking for a numeric solution at a particular value of $t$.

Comment: Yes, I want to find y(5).

Comment: But I feel that Euler's method would be too bashy. Is it the right way to go? @1110101001

Comment: @SakethMalyala That would work, but it's one of the slowest converging methods. More accurate/faster converging methods are more tedious. Honestly I would just grab a computer and have it solve it. I got y(5)=10.785

Comment: I would use a Fourth Order Runge-Kutta Algorithm. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods

Comment: “Lovolera” = Lotka–Volterra...

Comment: oops. i basically slept every day after the big exam @HansLundmark

Comment: Something like Matlab's ode45 is an easy way to handle this. Symbolic methods are basically wasting your time in most nonlinear problems.

Comment: A starting point $(x(0),y(0))=(600,800)$ seems awfully far from where the action takes place (basically, around the fixed point $(x^*,y^*)=(1,1)$). Sure there is no unit mistake there?

Comment: Since you are still active on the site... what are your plans about the present page? A) To answer my query? B) To leave the page in disarray? C) To close it? My personal preference goes to A)...